# Generate random number from 2 different ranges

Tags: c#, random

How can I generate a random number from two different ranges?

For example: one number from 10-20 and 50-60.

I know how to generate a random number from one range (1-13):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int num = rnd.Next(1, 13);
```

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @avisikirov if you can generate for one how come you can't do it for the others you have the coded example that you posted..?

Comment: Could it be that OP wants to generate a single number that falls in the range of 10-20 or 50-60, and not two separate numbers from those ranges?

Comment: @jaredk ah, good thinking. In that case I'd suggest the OP generates 3 numbers; one for each range and then a third to dictate which one to use. Like Robert did in his answer, now that I look at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int num = rnd.Next(1, 3)==1 ? rnd.Next(10, 21) : rnd.Next(50,61);
```

or

```
int num = rnd.Next(10, 32);
if (num>20) num+=29;
```

or just for fun (don't use with large ranges, and runs slow anyhow):

```
var ranges=new []{ Tuple.Create(10,20), Tuple.Create(50,60)};
var rnd=new Random();
var possible=ranges.Select(x=>Enumerable.Range(x.Item1,x.Item2-x.Item1+1))
  .SelectMany(x=>x)
  .Distinct();
var num=possible.Skip(rnd.Next(0,possible.Count())).First();
```

Comment: It should be `rnd.Next(1, 3)`. The max value is exclusive.

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thank you, your first method is wonderful. but can I use this method for taking random numbers from 3 groups or even more?

Comment: Sure.  The 3rd method can take however many groups you need, just add another Tuple.  The first and second methods can be modified to handle more groups.  Modifying the first to handle 3 groups would look like: `switch(rnd.Next(1,4)){ case 1: num=rnd.Next(10,21); break; case 2: num=rnd.Next(50,61); break; case 3: num=rnd.Next(90,101); break;}`

Comment: The first method will favor some numbers more than others if the size of the ranges are not the same however.  Like 1-2 and 10-19.  1 would show up 25% of the time, 2 would show up 25% of the time, and each number 10-19 would show up 5% of the time, so be careful.

Comment: Alternatively, you can do a modification of the second method.  For 10-20, 50-60, 90-100, it would look like: `int tmp=rnd.Next(0,33); int num; if (tmp<11) num=tmp+10; else if (tmp<22) num=tmp+39; else num=tmp+68;`

Comment: @RobertMcKee Thank you for the comment. There is a way of generating ranudom numbers not including some numbers? for exapmple: random number from 20-50 not including 25,27,34.

Comment: Yes, ask for 20-24,26-26,28-33, and 35-50.

Comment: Or you could do: `Enumerable.Range(0, int.MaxValue).Select(x=>rnd.Next(20,51)).Where(x=>x!=25 && x!=27 && x!=34).First();` although, that essentially just rerolls when it gets one of those numbers, and will throw an exception if it rerolls 2 billion times (or whatever int.MaxValue is).  Not likely to happen, but...

Answer (score 2):

Remember for the Next method, the lower bound is inclusive, while the upper bound is exclusive.  How about:

```
var rand = new Random();
var num1 = rand.Next(10, 21);

var num2 = rand.Next(50, 61);

var myNum = rand.Next(0, 2) == 1 ? num1 : num2;
```

Comment: Thank you, your method is wonderful. but can I use this method for taking random numbers from 3 groups or even more?

Comment: Yes, it could be extended to support any number of groups.  I think the basic example is good though because it's easy to understand and answers your question.

Answer (score 2):

You are generating 22 distinct random numbers, 10-20 and 50-60. So do that first:

```
int randomNumber = rnd.Next(0, 22);
```

Now, you have random numbers from 0 to 21.

Add ten:

```
randomNumber += 10;
```

Now, you have random numbers between from 10 to 31.

Add 29 for all numbers >= 21:

```
if (randomNumber >= 21) {
    randomNumber += 29;
}
```

Now, you have random numbers from 10 to 20, and from 50 to 60.

Comment: Tip: you don't have to specify the lower bound when it is 0. So rnd.Next(22); would also do it.

Answer (score 2):

A more general approach would be to make an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) for the `Random` class in which you add `NextFromRanges` and `NextDoubleFromRanges` methods. So it will work for any given number of ranges of any type.
First you need to define a `Range` class. Make it [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) so you can reuse it for different types, not only for example for `int` ranges but also for `double`.

```
/// <summary>The Range class.</summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Generic parameter.</typeparam>
public class Range<T>
{
    /// <summary>Minimum value of the range.</summary>
    public T Minimum { get; set; }

    /// <summary>Maximum value of the range.</summary>
    public T Maximum { get; set; }

    public Range(T min, T max)
    {
        Minimum = min;
        Maximum = max;
    }
}

public static class RandomExtension
{
    static Random random = new Random();

    public static int NextFromRanges(this Random random, List<Range<int>> ranges)
    {
        int randomRange = random.Next(0, ranges.Count);
        return random.Next(ranges[randomRange].Minimum, ranges[randomRange].Maximum);
    }

    public static double NextDoubleFromRanges(this Random random, List<Range<double>> ranges)
    {
        int randomRange = random.Next(0, ranges.Count);
        double doubleNrRange = ranges[randomRange].Maximum - ranges[randomRange].Minimum;
        return ranges[randomRange].Minimum + random.NextDouble()*doubleNrRange;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
    //instantiate a Random generator
    Random random = new Random();

    //define three integer ranges
    List<Range<int>> intRanges = new List<Range<int>>();
    intRanges.Add(new Range<int>(0, 10));
    intRanges.Add(new Range<int>(50, 60));
    intRanges.Add(new Range<int>(100, 110));

    //define three double ranges
    List<Range<double>> doubleRanges = new List<Range<double>>();
    doubleRanges.Add(new Range<double>(0, 5.5));
    doubleRanges.Add(new Range<double>(50, 55.5));
    doubleRanges.Add(new Range<double>(100, 105.5));

    //generate a random number between one of above three ranges
    //it is shown in the Visual Studio - Output window (Ctrl-W,O)
    Console.WriteLine(random.NextFromRanges(intRanges));
    Console.WriteLine(random.NextDoubleFromRanges(doubleRanges));
```

It will produce:
-random `int` number between one of the three given `int` ranges: 0-10, 50-60 and 100-110.
-random `double` number between one of the three given `double` ranges: 0-5.5, 50-55.5, 100-105.5

Just like the [Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Random_Next_System_Int32_System_Int32_) and [NextDouble](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.nextdouble?view=netframework-4.7.2) methods the **upperbound is exclusive**.

You'll now have two extra methods added to the standard [Random](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) class:
[image]

Answer (score -2):

You could write your own Random class. Where you rewrite the Next method with a new overload that would accept an even number of arguments.

It would look something like:

```
Random.NextFromGroups(10, 20, 50, 60, 100, 110);
```

Where the number-pairs mean the ranges.

Signature:

```
int NextFromGroups(params int[]);
```

and it would throw an Exception when it gets an odd number of arguments.